# Is it possible to upgrade from Apache Solr 4.7.2 directly to Apache Solr 7.6?

Tags: solr, upgrade

We are looking to upgrade from Apache Solr 4.7.2 to ApacheSolr 7.6. The documentation is not very clear.
Please reply with your valuable notes

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try already? In what sense documentation is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As seen on the [reference page for the Index Upgrader tool](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/indexupgrader-tool.html):

> Indexes can only be upgraded from the previous major release version to the current major release version.
>
> This means that the IndexUpgrader Tool in any Solr 7.x release, for example, can only work with indexes from 6.x releases, but cannot work with indexes from Solr 5.x or earlier.
>
> If you are currently using an earlier release such as 5.x and want to move more than one major version ahead, you need to first upgrade your indexes to the next major version (6.x), then again to the major version after that (7.x), etc.

There's also an [indexupgrader tool](https://github.com/cominvent/solr-tools/tree/master/upgradeindex) that attempts to perform this sequence automagically for you from your current version.

Comment: can you please share any other code/URL reference to upgrade apache solr from 4.7 to 7.6(https://github.com/cominvent/solr-tools/tree/master/upgradeindex is not worked for us)

Comment: @Shinu  Please create a new question and include the proper details to why it didn't work and what challenges you're seeing. Usually the easiest way to upgrade across a large version gap is to reconfigure and then reindex.

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm working with Shinu for upgrading the apache solr from 4.7 to 7.6.
For that, I've set up a test apache solr server with 5.2, i've moved the old data and config file and getting the below error.

**`SolrCore Initialization Failures
collection1: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core collection1: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "pint": Error loading class 'solr.IntField'. Schema file is /home/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml`**

.


Let me know to use the upgrade index script

Comment: ./upgradeindex.sh -t 5 /home/solr

Comment: That's an issue with the IntField changing to the new Point-based types. But please create a new question - the comments isn't a place to ask new questions and provide details.

Comment: @MatsLindh we have created a new question with details(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300930/apache-solr-index-upgrade-from-4-7-to-5-2). Please help us to resolve the issues.