# Apache Solr index upgrade from 4.7 to 5.2

Tags: solr, data-migration, reindex

We are looking to upgrade from Apache Solr 4.7 to ApacheSolr 5.2.
upgraded server and run [script](https://github.com/cominvent/solr-tools/tree/master/upgradeindex) to upgrade the data index. it is showing below errors.

```
./upgradeindex.sh -t 5 /home/solr
Target version is 5
Downloading http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-backward-codecs/4.10.4/lucene-backward-codecs-4.10.4.jar
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
Downloading http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-backward-codecs/5.5.4/lucene-backward-codecs-5.5.4.jar
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
Downloading http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-backward-codecs/6.6.0/lucene-backward-codecs-6.6.0.jar
######################################################################## 100.0%
Downloading http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/4.10.4/lucene-core-4.10.4.jar
######################################################################## 100.0%
Downloading http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/5.5.4/lucene-core-5.5.4.jar
######################################################################## 100.0%
Downloading http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/6.6.0/lucene-core-6.6.0.jar
######################################################################## 100.0%
Core collection1 - /home/solr/collection1
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: /home/solr/collection1/data/index/write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.<init>(CheckIndex.java:401)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.doMain(CheckIndex.java:2671)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.main(CheckIndex.java:2599)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: /home/solr/collection1/data/index/write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.<init>(CheckIndex.java:362)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.doMain(CheckIndex.java:2307)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.main(CheckIndex.java:2235)
- Backing up index to /home/solr/collection1/data/index_backup_4.7.0.tgz
- Index version is 4.7.0, checking integrity
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: /home/solr/collection1/data/index/write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.<init>(CheckIndex.java:362)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.doMain(CheckIndex.java:2307)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.main(CheckIndex.java:2235)
- Upgrading 4.x -> 5.x
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: /home/solr/collection1/data/index/write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:776)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader.upgrade(IndexUpgrader.java:167)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader.main(IndexUpgrader.java:78)
DONE
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you upgrad your index-files instead of reindex your data at the new 5.2 core?

Comment: I am trying to reindex the data not upgrade index file

Comment: Are you upgrading to 5.2? The upgrade script tries to upgrade you to Solr 7 .. and are you doing this while Solr is still running? .. and if you can reindex, you should do that instead.

Comment: @MatsLindh, our plan is to upgrade our current solr data in the 4.7.2 to 7.6, for that first we trying to upgrade to 5.2 version. we are doing this while solr running. please advice with your valuable suggestion.

Comment: First, stop Solr. The error message is telling you that the Solr index is locked by the running server.